# MapView with local search

Tags: ios, location, mkmapview, mapkit

I've a question about doing a local search in Apple maps which I have already implemented into my app. 
The app should show the user where are "supermarkets" around him. My mapView also shows the user's current location but I don't really know how I should do this with the results of the market-locations. Maybe Apple provides a solution/advice for this.
Thanks in advance.

[image: The results (supermarkets) should be displayed as in this picture]

The results (supermarkets) should be displayed as in this picture.

**UPDATE:**
The function works perfectly but is it also possible to make these *pins* clickable to show an info-sheet about this location as in the pictures below?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm so fascinated from this map-implemention, so I wonder if it's also possible to get infos about your current location (as in the screenshot below).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6.1 and later, you can use [`MKLocalSearch`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html), adding annotations for each of the [`MKMapItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html) objects you find.

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"supermarket";
request.region = mapView.region;

MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
    {
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate;
        annotation.title      = item.name;
        annotation.subtitle   = item.placemark.title;
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}];
```

If you want the right and left accessories on your callouts, you should implement a `viewForAnnotation` that adds those accessories (and of course, for this to work, you have to define your controller to be the `delegate` for your `MKMapView`):

```
typedef enum : NSInteger
{
    kCallOutAccessoryRight = 1,
    kCallOutAccessoryLeft
} CallOutAccessoryType;

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    static NSString *identifier = @"customAnnotationView";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView     = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag = kCallOutAccessoryRight;

        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView      = ...; // whatever you want for the left button
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView.tag  = kCallOutAccessoryLeft;
    }
    else
    {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

And, you presumably want to respond to the user tapping on those callouts:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    if (control.tag == kCallOutAccessoryRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Present info sheet for %@ here", [view.annotation title]);
    }
    else if (control.tag == kCallOutAccessoryLeft)
    {
        NSLog(@"Do whatever you want if left accessory tapped");
    }
}
```

---

You asked how to present the user directions. Yes, you can do that by passing it a `MKMapItem` to `openMapsWithItems`. But that presumes that you save the `MKMapItem` from the local search. To do this, you're creating a custom annotation. For example:

```
//  MapItemAnnotation.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapItemAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) MKMapItem *item;

- (id)initWithMapItem:(MKMapItem *)item;
- (NSString *)title;
- (NSString *)subtitle;
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

And

```
//  MapItemAnnotation.m

#import "MapItemAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapItemAnnotation

- (id)initWithMapItem:(MKMapItem *)item
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _item = item;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSString *)title
{
    return _item.name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return _item.placemark.title;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    return _item.placemark.coordinate;
}

@end
```

Having done that, your adding the annotation to your maps is simplified a bit:

```
[search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
    {
        MapItemAnnotation *annotation = [[MapItemAnnotation alloc] initWithMapItem:item];
        [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}];
```

But, now, your left callout accessory can easily initiate directions in Apple Maps:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    if (control.tag == kCallOutAccessoryRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"Present info sheet for %@ here", [view.annotation title]);
    }
    else if (control.tag == kCallOutAccessoryLeft)
    {
        // request directions from Apple Maps

        MapItemAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
        NSAssert([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapItemAnnotation class]], @"Annotation should be MapItemAnnotation: %@", annotation);

        [annotation.item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey      : [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinate:mapView.region.center],
                                                       MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey        : [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:mapView.region.span],
                                                       MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];
    }
}
```

---

Regarding updating the user location description, you can define a [`didUpdateUserLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3adidUpdateUserLocation%3a) method (i.e. the map view calls this [`MKMapViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204) method every time the user's location changes). It looks like you want to update the subtitle for the user's location:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [self updateSubtitleForUserLocation:userLocation];
}
```

That would call this method that would do the reverse geocode and update the subtitle accordingly:

```
- (void)updateSubtitleForUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if ([self.geocoder isGeocoding])
        [self.geocoder cancelGeocode];

    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:userLocation.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        MKPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
        userLocation.subtitle = placemark.name;
    }];
}
```

Clearly, you need a class property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLGeocoder *geocoder;
```

And you need to instantiate that, e.g. `viewDidLoad` could:

```
self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
```

I might refine this a bit to only do a reverse geocode if the user's location has changed by more than *x* meters (you don't want to do too many reverse geocode requests; you'll kill the user's battery), but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: It depends. If the user is manually panning around on the map, you might do this in response to `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` (though you'd add logic to check to make sure you hadn't already added the particular annotation). If you're allowing `userTrackingMode` of `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`, you might add some more logic to ensure you don't call this redundantly too often.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with my second question (get an info-sheet)

Comment: @user2242550 See revised answer.

Comment: And one last question: is it possible to navigate to one of the pins?

Comment: ...or is it possible to jump into the apple maps

Comment: @user2242550 Yes, pull up the directions in Apple Maps. It involves a slight refactoring of the code to use a custom annotation that keeps track of the original `MKMapItem`, but the [`openInMapsWithLaunchOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011746-CH1-SW14) makes it really easy to do if you've saved the original map item in the annotation like this.

Comment: As you are very familiar to the mapKit you can maybe help me with the new part of my question ;)

Comment: @user2242550 See [Converting Coordinates Into Place Name Information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW2)

Comment: Hm...quite difficult to understand for me. Do I have to implement CLGeocorder?

Comment: Maybe you can give me a code example as I'm very new to Xcode

Comment: @user2242550 I've revised my answer, but I'd suggest you stop editing this question and adding more questions to it. 1. If you have another question, ask a separate question. 2. And if you want to bring our attention to it, add a comment here with a link to that new question. 3. And, also, I would have thought that you would have gotten tons of answers if you googled that method referenced in that link I shared in my previous comment, e.g. google "reverseGeocodeLocation example".

Comment: Ok...thanks, but next time I will pay attention to your advice