# Display current location converted to Geocoder on ios Map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, core-location

What is best way to display current location in to geo coder string!!
Instead of "Current location";
[image]

Following code only works first time !!! if location change then It will not update location.

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation{
if (annotation == mapView.userLocation){


    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.brokendownMapview.userLocation.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
          if ((placemarks != nil) && (placemarks.count > 0)) {
              // If the placemark is not nil then we have at least one placemark. Typically there will only be one.
              _placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];


              // we have received our current location, so enable the "Get Current Address" button
              CLS_LOG(@"What is location %@",_placemark);



              _currentLocation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_placemark];
              NSString *locationName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_placemark.name];
              self.myMapView.userLocation.title =locationName;
                NSString *localityAndPostcode =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",_placemark.locality,_placemark.postalCode];
              self.myMapView.userLocation.subtitle = localityAndPostcode;
          }
          else {
              // Handle the nil case if necessary.
              self.myMapView.userLocation.title =@"Location is unknown";
              self.myMapView.userLocation.subtitle =@"";

          }
      }];


    return nil;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `CLLocationManager` for updating location and getting location details?

Comment: Yes, How to implement that?

Comment: Create an instance of `CLLocationManager` and start location updates. The location updates can be caught in the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`. Use the location object for reverse geocoding and make your map annotation with that location details.

Comment: Do you mean in 
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{  // my code should go here} <<<<This did not work

Comment: Although you could use CLLocationManager's didUpdateLocations delegate method, it's not necessary because MKMapView already has its own didUpdateUserLocation delegate method.  See an example of how to update the user location title with the current address at the bottom of [this answer by Rob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682834/mapview-with-local-search).